# How to chain a condition on a json type

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Let's say I have the following json object array in a BigQuery query:

```
with tbl as (
  select json '''{
  "products": {
    "product": [
      {
        "territory": "CA",
        "sales_start_date": "2023-05-05"
      },
      {
        "territory": "US",
        "sales_start_date": "2023-06-05"
      }
    ]
  }
}''' as j)
select json_extract_array(j, '$.products.product') from tbl
```

How would I chain the condition of `WHERE territory="CA" AND sales_start_date="2023-05-05"` to the query? I have broken the json value into an array, but I'm not sure where to go from there. Clearly, I need an unnest, but when I try that on the json array, it tells me:

> Second argument to IN UNNEST of type ARRAY is not supported because array element type is not equality comparable at [16:10]

So how would I solve this? (by the way, translated into xpath it would be the following query: `//products/product[territory="CA" and sales_start_date="2023-05-05"]`).

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to do this would be using `UNNEST` in the table clause. Here would be an example:

```
with tbl as (
  select json '''{
  "products": {
    "product": [
      {
        "territory": "CA",
        "sales_start_date": "2023-05-05"
      },
      {
        "territory": "US",
        "sales_start_date": "2023-06-05"
      }
    ]
  }
}''' as j)
select j from tbl, unnest(json_query_array(j, '$.products.product')) j2 
where STRING(j2.territory)="CA" and STRING(j2.sales_start_date)="2023-05-05"
```

Notice it's required to cast the `json` value to `string` in the `WHERE` clause (bigquery does not allow equality checks on json types)`.